# Change font size in two column layout Quarto

Tags: r, layout, quarto, reveal.js

I would like to change the font size of one part of a two-column layout in Quarto. Here is some reproducible code without changing the font size:

```
---
output: revealjs
---

:::: {.columns}

::: {.column width="40%"}
Example list:

* unordered list
    + sub-item 1
    + sub-item 2
        - sub-sub-item 1
:::

::: {.column width="60%"}
![Here's an elephant](https://www.r-project.org/logo/Rlogo.png)
:::

::::
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see this works great. The two-column layout is nice. Imagine I want to change the font size of the text part (first column), we could use `style="font-size: 50%;"` to reduce the font size like this:

```
:::: {.columns}

::: {.column width="40%" style="font-size: 50%;"}
Example list:

* unordered list
    + sub-item 1
    + sub-item 2
        - sub-sub-item 1
:::

::: {.column width="60%"}
![Here's an elephant](https://www.r-project.org/logo/Rlogo.png)
:::

::::
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see the font size is indeed reduced, but the layout is not the same again. The picture is moved more to the left. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to reduce the font size of a column in a two-column layout without shifting the items?

Comment: Can you avoid using `elephant.png` since it requires downloading the image from somewhere? Is there the same behavior with a plot or a table?

Comment: @bretauv, You could copy all the text of "Example list:" and replace that with the image. The same will happen.

Comment: Ok so maybe you should edit your post like this, so that it can just be copy-pasted without needing an image

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that the column width is set via the `style` attribute. However, by setting the `font-size` via the `style` attribute you are overwriting the defaults and the column width gets dropped:

[image]

Perhaps there is default option to set the font size without overwriting the defaults. But a possible fix would be to set the column width via the `style` attribute, too:

```
---
output: revealjs
---

:::: {.columns}

::: {.column style="width: 40%; font-size: 50%;"}
Example list:

* unordered list
    + sub-item 1
    + sub-item 2
        - sub-sub-item 1
:::

::: {.column width="60%"}
![Here's an elephant](https://www.r-project.org/logo/Rlogo.png)
:::

::::
```

[image]